# Accessing tableviews using accessibility identifiers UIAutomation

Tags: uitableview, ios6, ios-ui-automation

I have two table views on the app say TableViewA and TableViewB. Both my tableviews has groups and cells. My TableviewB (along with its groups and cells) is a subview of cells of TableViewA. So in short, cells of tableViewA holds entire tableviewB.

In UIAutomation I can access tableviewB using

`tableViewA.cells()[0].tableviewB()[0]`

But my tableViewB has an accessibilityIdentifier set to it say "shoppingTable".

Now using accessibilityIdentifier, how can I access tableViewB??

Comment: Is your table view returning YES from `isAccessibilityElement`? You need to do that for the identifier to be visible in UI Automation.

Comment: I haven't tried isAccessibilityElement it on any of the elements yet, but I am able to get the accessibility identifiers for other elements. I use getElementByName('accessibilityIdentifierName') and I am able to get the element.

Comment: I will try isAccessibilityElement on this.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the table views are being seen properly you should try running logElementTree() on the mainWindow(). It is common for nested views to be hidden because in Apple documentation they note that if you have a container view and it is set as the accessibility element it hides all of the children. There are workarounds for this posted in numerous blog posts.

Given that your table A isn't hiding table B, by using

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();
```

You can print out the view and you should see the identifier you are looking for